# executing jmeters junit sampler with maven

Tags: maven, jenkins, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I want to perform load tests on a jmeters junit sampler by using maven and want  report the  performanceresults. I used 10 threads with a ramp up period of 5 sec.here is my pom file

```
enter code here   <properties>
        <selenium.version>3.0.1</selenium.version>      
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/junit/junit -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>          
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>${selenium.version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-classes</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <junitLibraries>
                      <artifact>com.lazerycode.junit:junit-test:1.0.0</artifact>
                        </junitLibraries>
                    <propertiesGlobal>
                        <threads>10</threads>
                        <rampup>5</rampup>
                    </propertiesGlobal>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Please help me if it is a right way to call jmeter's junit request sampler.If not please help me with the corrections.

Also please help me how to report the performance results(e.g.reports)

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0):

As per [Adding additional libraries to the classpath](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Adding-additional-libraries-to-the-classpath) chapter of the [JMeter Maven Plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) documentation you should place dependencies under `<jmeterExtensions>` tag like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>jmeter-selenium-junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>jmeter-selenium-junit-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>your-junit-jar</id>
            <name>your junit repo</name>
            <url>file:/path/to/your-junit-jar.jar</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.lazerycode.jmeter</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmeter-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jmeter-tests</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>jmeter</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <jmeterExtensions>
                        <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-java:3.0.1</artifact>
                        <artifact>org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-firefox-driver:3.0.1</artifact>
                    </jmeterExtensions>
                    <junitLibraries>
                        <artifact>com.yourcompany.yourgroup:your-artifact:1.0-SNAPSHOT</artifact>
                    </junitLibraries>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

---

Also be aware that there is a [WebDriver Sampler JMeter Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which provides seamless JMeter integration with Selenium so you won't have to recompile Selenium code each time and have it inlined directly into .jmx file.